# Ubuntu (default) power management

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, performance, cpu

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13 laptop. I have noticed that the CPUs is sometimes very slow (after disconnecting or reconnecting the AC cable; not sure about the dependency though because I only noticed on CPU-intensive tasks).
I figured that the reason for that was that the CPU Governor was set to `powersave`. Setting it to `performance` manually with `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance` resolves the issue.

However, I would expect that to be done automatically by default, so I started doing some research about power management in Ubuntu (18.04). However, it remains unclear to me how power management works by default, as well as how to improve/adapt it.

To summarize my findings/hypotheses:

- There are power profiles (`performance`, `balanced`, and `powersave`) that also set the CPU governor (`powersave`, `performance`) and other things (what?). CPU governors are presumably hardware-specific (really?), whereas the power profiles are not(?).
- I have [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/) (not sure whether it is installed in a default installation) running, which is supposed to change power settings, depending on the battery/charger status and other factors(?). I see in the logs that `tlp auto` is actually triggered when I connect or disconnect the charger. However, I don't see any consequences of that in terms of power settings (at least for the CPU governors).
- The Gnome [cpufreq extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/) shows me that neither the power profile nor the CPU governors are changed when I connect/disconnect the charger.

The Ubuntu documentation is rather unspecific (see the [PowerManagement community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement), [PowerManagement wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement)) and wildly outdated, refering to Ubuntu 08.04-10.04.

My underlying questions is: is there any up-to-date documentation about Ubuntu power management, clarifying the terminology and the default software?

More specifically:

- How can I set up Ubuntu so that it switches power management automatically when (dis-)connecting the charger?
- Is this supposed to be the case by default? As it is apparently not in my setup, how can I debug/fix it?
- Is TLP fine to live next to (default) power management, or is this conflicting?
- What is TLP supposed to do, and how can I find out why it does not seem to do anything?

Comment: One update: checking the output of `sudo tlp-stat -p` reveals only one difference per CPU, when the charger is plugged/unplugged: the value of 
`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference` changes between `balance_power` (when the charger is not connected) and `balance_performance` (when not connected).

Not sure how/if this is related to the other  points.

Comment: Unfortunately, Dell laptops are known to have some issues related to non-original or malfunctioning power adapters. Seems similar to your case: https://superuser.com/questions/1160735/stop-dell-from-throttling-cpu-with-power-adapter

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I don't think that is the issue, because the adapter is actually detected. Connecting or disconnecting the charger does trigger a `tlp auto` execution.

Comment: Another update: it seems like the `tlp` settings are actually effective. For instance, I've changed them to allow cpu boost on ac, and by tracing the maximum CPU seep, I can see that this is indeed allowed. The power profile, however, is not changed; not sure where this is set in general.